# Execute multiple scripts on multiple servers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a multiple scripts I need to execute on test servers (we have 20 test servers)
Is there any method for doing this quickly or any tool that can manage this vs doing the whole process manually?

Answer (score 0):

Beside using SQLCMD which is a manual and time consuming process, or Server groups in SSMS you can also use a third party tool, ApexSQL Build.

Here is the article with a detailed explanation on how to accomplish this using this tool: [SQL Database deployment on several different SQL Server instances and databases](http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/deploy-multiple-sql-scripts-to-multiple-servers/)

*Disclaimer: I work for ApexSQL as a Support Engineer*